# Find interval of convergence K of $f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{2^n.x^n.x}{n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{2^n.x^n.x}{n} $$
So I let x out side and i got this:$$f(x) =x.\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{2^n.x^n}{n} $$
then i use root criterion and i got $$2|x|$$
Can you help me how can i get rid of the x. Thank you so much

Comment: You are nearly there! Just solve for $2|x|<1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ratio test to find out the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{2}$. Also when $x=\frac{1}{2}$ the series is Harmonic Series and it diverges. When $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, the series converges by the alternating series test. Hence the interval of convergence is $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

The root criterion says that for 
$$a_n = \frac{2^nx^n}{n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}} = \beta$$
$\beta$ determined by x and if $\beta$ < 1 then the sequence converges and f(x) has a value.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} {\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n|x^n|}{n}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac{2|x|}{\sqrt[n]{n}}} = 2|x| = \beta$$
since $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n} = 1$.
Since sequence converges when $\beta < 1$, $\beta = 2|x| < 1$ so $|x| < 1/2$.
That is the same as $-1/2 < x < 1/2$. Also the region of convergence has a radius of 1/2.